# Play 2.3.7 and Sbt's evicted warning on Netty

Tags: sbt

Using Sbt 0.13.7 and Play! 2.3.7 I get the following warning on evicted libraries:

```
[info]  io.netty:netty
[info]      - 3.9.3.Final
[info]          status: release
[info]          publicationDate: Wed Aug 06 20:59:02 CEST 2014
[info]          resolver: sbt-chain
[info]          artifactResolver: sbt-chain
[info]          evicted: false
[info]          homepage: http://netty.io/
[info]          isDefault: false
[info]          configurations: compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master
[info]          licenses: (Apache License, Version 2.0,Some(http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0))
[info]          callers: com.typesafe.netty:netty-http-pipelining:1.1.2, com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.3.7
[info]      - 3.6.3.Final
[info]          evicted: true
[info]          evictedData: latest-revision
[info]          configurations: compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master
[info]          callers: com.typesafe.netty:netty-http-pipelining:1.1.2
...
[info]  org.webjars:jquery
[info]      - 2.1.3
[info]          status: release
[info]          publicationDate: Thu Dec 18 17:24:20 CET 2014
[info]          resolver: sbt-chain
[info]          artifactResolver: sbt-chain
[info]          evicted: false
[info]          homepage: http://webjars.org
[info]          isDefault: false
[info]          configurations: default(compile), default, compile, runtime, master, master(*), compile(*), runtime(*)
[info]          licenses: (MIT License,Some(https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt))
[info]          callers: org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.2, mdpm:caving_2.11:0.1.0
[info]      - 1.11.1
[info]          evicted: true
[info]          evictedData: latest-revision
[info]          configurations: compile, master(*), runtime, compile(*), runtime(*), master
[info]          callers: org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.2
```

Why is

- `com.typesafe.netty:netty-http-pipelining:1.1.2` wrt. `io.netty:netty`
- `org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.2` wrt `org.webjars:jquery`

listed in both sections? E.g., is `bootstrap:3.3.2` using jQuery 1.11.1 and 2.1.3? I guess not. What am I missing here?

Finally, how to resolve those "issues"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update report from Ivy doesn't distinguish (I think)

1. the original caller
2. modified caller that happened because of eviction
3. or, the transitive callers

To get to the bottom of the situation, you have to [search for the POM in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.webjars%22%20AND%20a%3A%22bootstrap%22). It says that bootstrap 3.3.2 uses jQuery 1.11.1.

Netty shows up because sbt was not able to handle `.Final` thing.

> Finally, how to resolve those "issues"?

It depends on the compatibility provided by the individual libraries. Eviction warning by default uses Semantic Versioning to infer compatibilities when a library is not cross built (without `_2.11` postfixes). Here are several things you can do:

- If you find out that jQuery 1.11.1 and 2.1.3 are compatible ([they are](http://jquery.com/download/) except 2.x no longer supports IE 6/7/8), you can choose to ignore the warning.
- You can [override](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version) to a specific version of your choice.
- In the cases you actually *do* have incompatibilities, you would need to upgrade or downgrade your libraries so the compatibilities line up. This might entail contacting the authors, or building things yourself.

Comment: For the record, I removed the explicit jQuery import `"org.webjars" %"jquery" % "2.1.3"` relying on the implicit via Bootstrap. Next, I added the override directive `dependencyOverrides ++= Set("io.netty" % "netty" % "3.9.3.Final")` resulting in "empty" output of `evicted`. Thanks Eugene.